# COUNT matching results of SUMIFS

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to figure out how many people in my raw data is within a certain average handling time range. There is no issue finding out the average handling time for the specific criteria, but when I add the factor of asking "how many unique individuals are there?" I'm totally blocked..

I do not want to use helper tables, as I would need about 30 tables, and since they are dynamic both vertically and horizontally, 30 worksheets.

Example of raw data:

| Date | Person | Total handling time in seconds | Total interactions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-11 | Person A | 22453 | 46 |
| 2021-07-11 | Person B | 22249 | 36 |
| 2021-07-12 | Person A | 17970 | 34 |
| 2021-07-12 | Person B | 5367 | 9 |

So now, if I take this:

```
=(SUMIFS(table1[Total handling time],table1[Date],"2021-07-11")/86400)
/
(SUMIFS(table1[Total interactions],table1[Date],">2021-07-11")
```

Then I get 0.00630966 which formats as 9 minutes and 5 seconds.

I now know that that is less than 10 minutes, so I can wrap an IF condition around it and get to know that this person is within the time frame. **But how do I instead get the result to be "1" instead, as in "One person met this criteria"?**

I would like to achieve this without helper columns etc. and if possible do it in one formula. I also cannot use a sumproduct formula, as the  date criteria is a spilled range, and in my experience, a sumproduct formula will not spill using a reference like "A1#" for example.

EDIT: Removed image of table as table is now fixed. Also, for clarification I want to do something like this (but it is not possible, as the AND criteria here is a criteria, and not a range:

```
=COUNTIFS(
          Person,"*",
          Date,"2021-07-11",
          AND(
              ((SUMIFS(Total handling time in seconds,Date,"2021-07-11")/86400)/SUMIFS(Total interactions,Date,$I$18))>0.00462962962962963,
              ((SUMIFS(Total handling time in seconds,Date,"2021-07-11")/86400)/SUMIFS(Total interactions,Date,$I$18))<0.00543981481481481
          ),TRUE
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your version of Excel you could use the `filter` function for this.

I replicated your table above in A1:D5, then used:

- J2 as a cutoff for the date
- J3 as upper limit for seconds/interaction
- J4 as lower limit for second/interaction

I took these out of the code for easier adjustments, and to make it easy to see current settings. Using seconds was mostly about me being lazy. (Note that if you set the filter so that no rows fulfill the criteria, the function will give an error code unless it's given an if-empty input. )

With this you can use

```
=FILTER(A2:D5,(A2:A5>$J$2)*((C2:C5/D2:D5)<$J$3)*((C2:C5/D2:D5)>$J$4))
```

to get a filtered version of the table. If you need different or more filters, just adjust in the form of `(true/false for array)*(true/false for array)*[...]`. In what I did here `C2:C5/D2:D5` creates a new array with the results of the calculation. If unsure, check the results with Evaluate Formula.

Put the filtered range into `index` to choose the second column, and wrap all of that into the `unique` function. Now you can simply take the `rows` of the array you get, if you want the number of persons with one or more dates that fulfill the conditions (which is what I think you're asking for). It would look like this:

```
=ROWS(UNIQUE(INDEX(
FILTER(A2:D5,(A2:A5>$J$2)*((C2:C5/D2:D5)<$J$3)*((C2:C5/D2:D5)>$J$4))
,,2)))
```

If you wanted to know which ones it is you can simply let the unique array spill and you'll see the values.

Comment: Thanks! I get a calc error though (using the same cells as you). Evaluating the formula I get `{44388;44388;44389;44389}>44390` for the first 'include' of the formula `(A2:A5>$J$2)` which gives {false;false;false;false}, then I get `{488;618;528;596}<470` for `((C2:C5/D2:D5)<$J$3)`, which becomes `{false;false;false;false}`, and finally `{488;618;528;596}>400` which gives `{true;true;true;true}` and finally #CALC

Comment: The calc error I think shows up because you apply a filter that takes away your whole dataset. I think the `filter` function has an input argument for when nothing is found, but maybe try first if it the problem goes away if you change some of your variables to allow one row to fulfill all the criteria.

Comment: Did this solve your problem @Strechingmycompetence?

Comment: HI! I tried it now and could not get rid of the error by entering an [if empty] value in the Filter formula (the last argument it takes). However, it seems to be working and have no idea what I did wrong earlier. I'll just throw an "iferror" around the whole formula. Thank you!

Comment: I spoke too early.. when I tried it on my actual data, it does not work. I evaluated each part of the formula and got a different amount of returns for all the arguments, so I guess that's what is the issue right now. I for example only got 1365 "FALSE" for the date range (I changed it to ="May" instead towards my month-column). Then 1472 results for my lower limit, 1287 results for my upper limit and 1566 for another added argument. I guess it can't compare the factors when the number of rows of results for each argument differs..

Comment: That you get a different number of FALSE in different columns shouldn't be a problem, as long as you use it over an area with the same rows. Filter is meant to take all these different answers for the true/false statements on a row, and if all of them are TRUE, to display that row in the return array. 

What error code/kind of fault are you getting? Can you manually find (or fake) a row that meets all of the criteria?